# source.on is not a function en Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente en Node.JS:

```
var file= './elemento1.pdf';

var formData = {
      'file': {
        data: fs.createReadStream(file),
        filename: 'elemento1',
        contentType: 'application/pdf'
      }
    };

compareAndComply.classifyElements(formData, function(error, response){
if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else { 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  }
});
```

Pero me manda el siguiente error:

```
source.on is not a function
```

¿Como puedo arreglarlo? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
var formData = {
 name: 'file1',
 file: {
   value:  fs.createReadStream('C:/kristian/Devbeasts-small.png'),
    options: {
    filename: 'elemento1.pdf',
    contentType: 'application/pdf'
  }
 }
};
```

Info en el siguiente [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, ya quedo!